# Write two dataframes to two different columns in CSV

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I converted two arrays into two dataframes and would like to write them to a CSV file in two separate columns. There are no common columns in the dataframes. I tried the solutions as follows and also from stack exchange but did not get the result. Solution 2 has no error but it prints all the data into one column. I am guessing that is a problem with how the arrays are converted to df? I basically want two column values of Frequency and PSD exported to csv. How do I do that ?

Solution 1:

```
df_BP_frq = pd.DataFrame(freq_BP[L_BP], columns=['Frequency'])
df_BP_psd = pd.DataFrame(PSDclean_BP[L_BP], columns=['PSD'])

df_BP_frq['tmp'] = 1
df_BP_psd['tmp'] = 1
df_500 = pd.merge(df_BP_frq, df_BP_psd, on=['tmp'], how='outer')
df_500 = df_500.drop('tmp', axis=1)
```

Error: Unable to allocate 2.00 TiB for an array with shape (274870566961,) and data type int64

Solution 2:

```
df_BP_frq = pd.DataFrame(freq_BP[L_BP], columns=['Frequency'])
df_BP_psd = pd.DataFrame(PSDclean_BP[L_BP], columns=['PSD'])

df_500 = df_BP_frq.merge(df_BP_psd, left_on='Frequency', right_on='PSD', how='outer')
```

No Error.
Result: The PSD values are all 0 and are seen below the frequency values in the lower rows.
[image]

Solution 3:

```
df_BP_frq = pd.DataFrame(freq_BP[L_BP], columns=['Frequency'])
df_BP_psd = pd.DataFrame(PSDclean_BP[L_BP], columns=['PSD'])

df_500 = pd.merge(df_BP_frq, df_BP_psd, on='tmp').ix[:, ('Frequency','PSD')]
```

Error: KeyError: 'tmp'

Exporting to csv using:

```
df_500.to_csv("PSDvalues500.csv", index = False, sep=',', na_rep = 'N/A', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directly store the array as columns of the dataframe. If the lengths of both arrays is same, the following method would work.

```
df_500 = pd.DataFrame()
df_500['Frequency'] = freq_BP[L_BP]
df_500['PSD'] = PSDclean_BP[L_BP]
```

If the lengths of the arrays are different, you can convert them to series and then add them as columns in the following way. This would make add `nan` for empty values in the dataframe.

```
df_500 = pd.DataFrame()
df_500['Frequency'] = pd.Series(freq_BP[L_BP])
df_500['PSD'] = pd.Series(PSDclean_BP[L_BP])
```

Comment: Noted. But this does not solve the problem of how df is exported to CSV. I still get everything in the same column.

Comment: that might be an issue with your CSV viewer application. do other CSV files open fine? maybe try a different separator while exporting to CSV. `df.to_csv('output_filename.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: So the delimeter was the problem. Thank you ! Why did it work with ; and not with \t or , ? Is there a way to check which delimeter is exactly being used ?

Comment: I think you can change the delimiter in the application that you are using to read CSVs. That seems to be the issue. To check the delimiter you can first open the file in a normal text editor (SublimeText, etc.). If reading in pandas, you'd have to specify the delimiter, it it's anything other than a comma.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is that you have two arrays you want to store them into one dataframe different columns and save that dataframe to csv with separate columns .

Creating two Numpy arrays of equal length .

```
import numpy as np 
n1 = np.arange(2, 100, 0.01)
n2 = np.arange(3, 101, 0.01)
```

Creating an empty dataframe and storing the above arrays as columns of the dataframe

```
n = pd.DataFrame()
n['feq']= n1
n['psd'] = n2
```

Storing into Csv

```
n.to_csv(r"C\:...\dataframe.csv",index= False)
```

If they are unequal dataframes convert them as series and then store them in empty  dataframe .